# Can't create ASP.NET MVC 5 project after updating Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to upgrade a project from ASP.NET MVC 4 to ASP.NET MVC 5. I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2012 on a VM and I checked on the Internet how to do so. I installed `ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012` (whose name is now 2012.2 update) and from what I've seen on the web I should be able to create a `new ASP.NET MVC 5 Empty Project` in Visual Studio. But nothing has changed and I can't see the ASP.NET MVC 5 in my projects creation list :

[Project creation (Sorry for French language)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6kal.png)

I installed it from the `Web Platform Installer` that asserts that the update has been installed (I actually uninstalled it and installed it again to be sure) :

[Web Platform Installer 5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO59x.png)

I also tried to repair VS 2012.
If somebody already had this issue and knows how to solve it, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below link and try t install WebNode11Pack.exe from the link specified on the link below : 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/36985e/using-Asp-Net-mvc5-within-visual-studio-2012/

Link to downlaod the Webnode11Pack.exe is as under :
https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids

Comment: This is the tool I actually used to install the update.